# C#, Sql database and Nullable

Tags: c#

Как можно обойти эту проблему?

> Ошибка   1   "System.Nullable не содержит определение для "TotalDays". Не удалось найти метод  расширения "TotalDays", принимающий первый аргумент типа "System.Nullable"  (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?)

```
if(workAnimal.age_Group=="կով" && workAnimal.fructify_Day!=null){
    if ((DateTime.Now - workAnimal.fructify_Day).TotalDays == 19){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
(DateTime.Now - workAnimal.fructify_Day.Value).TotalDays
```

---

Объяснение: вы столкнулись с понятием nullable lifted operator. Тип `workAnimal.fructify_Day` есть не `DateTime`, а `DateTime?`, что то же самое, что и `Nullable<DateTime>`. Операции на структурах переносятся (lifted) на nullable-типы.

Таким образом, параллельно с вычитанием двух `DateTime`, автоматически определяется вычитание двух `DateTime?`.

В вашем случае `DateTime.Now` имеет тип `DateTime`, а вот `workAnimal.fructify_Day` — тип `DateTime?`. Вычесть `DateTime?` из `DateTime` так просто нельзя, но поскольку `DateTime` автоматически может сконвертироваться в `DateTime?` (но не наоборот), то `DateTime.Now` приводится к типу `DateTime?`. В реаультате происходит вычитание двух экземпляров `DateTime?`, что даёт результат типа `TimeSpan?`.

Откуда взялось такое правило? Если на пальцах: `DateTime?` — это значение, которое может быть `DateTime` или `null`. Если у вас слева и справа `DateTime`, то разность — нормальный `TimeSpan`. А вот если хотя бы один из них `null`, то никакого разумного результата проидумать нельзя, так что результатом будет тоже `null`. Значит, тип результата — `TimeSpan` или `null`, то есть в точности `TimeSpan?`.

Итак, разность `DateTime.Now - workAnimal.fructify_Day` имеет тип `TimeSpan?`. У этого типа нету поля `TotalDays` — отсюда и ошибка, которую вы получили.

Вы можете «вытащить» чистый `TimeSpan` через `.Value`, и уже у него запросить значение `TotalDays`. Или, поскольку ваш код проверяет, что `workAnimal.fructify_Day != null`, вы можете сразу вытащить значение чистого `DateTime` из `fructify_Day`, и дальше работать как обычно.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение и за ответ,все нормально работает

Comment: @Vardan: Пожалуйста!